# Tomcat with HTTPD front end. Manager app not accessible

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, ldap, tomcat, httpd

I have an HTTPD server which does the LDAP Authentication in front of Tomcat server. My application resides in the Tomcat.

I am proxying the authenticated requests via AJP connector of tomcat to my application. Now I want to close the HTTP connector. But the manager app is not accessible (saying 403 error).

- When I am accessing http://localhost/my_app. Everything works fine.
- When I am accessing http://localhost/manager/ , it gives me 403 error.
- With HTTP connector is open ie, http://localhost:port/manager, it is accessible.

Comment: Please provide your tomcat configuration

Comment: Its the default configuration. Only thing i have added extra is the Virtual Host, which uses ProxyPass and the ldap authentication.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It would be a help if you can reply based on default config since i have not changed anything

Comment: Can you share your virtualhost config?

Comment: ProxyPass / http://localhost:1000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1000/


<Proxy http://localhost:1000/>
                            BalancerMember ajp://localhost:1009/

    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
 AllowOverride None
 AuthName "Active Directory Authentication"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthBasicAuthoritative on
 AuthBasicProvider ldap
 LDAPReferrals off
 AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
 AuthLDAPURL 
 AuthLDAPBindDN 
 AuthLDAPBindPassword
 Require valid-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an educated guess. I think this might be a case of both the Manager part and Apache using HTTP authentication headers for authentication.

When the client connects to `http://localhost/manager`, Apache asks for authentication credentials for LDAP authentication. The client will then send the authentication information to Apache, which accepts the requests and passes it to Tomcat's manager part.

However, since the credentials are not what were defined for the manager, it returns 403 error.

The solution would be to exclude `/manager` part from the LDAP authentication. Unfortunately I don't know how that would be done within Apache.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that as well. But the manager app page is not properly loaded. It shows simply the elements of that page. Also, i tried giving the same credentials for the tomcatusers.xml. Then also it didn't work.

Comment: If it shows only HTML code, it means that the base URL of the application is not properly set. You need to find a setting for app root URL and make sure it is `http://localhost/manager`.

Answer (score 1):

based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808206/how-to-fix-tomcat-http-status-403-access-to-the-requested-resource-has-been-den

it seems that you are missing a role definition.

In the tomcat-users.xml file add a user with the role `manager` :

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
```

Comment: Nope... i am able to access manager through port which means my config is correct. I want to know how/ why it is not accessible when port number is not used